# How to make table view corner items corners round?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets, qtablewidgetitem

I have a `QTableWidget` (alternatively, a `QListWidget`) which I want to style in the following way:

- The "selected" color of the cells should be a certain fixed color. I am able to do this by using the following stylesheet:

  ```
  QTableWidget::item:selected { background-color: #FF0000 }
  ```
- The "unselected" color of the cells should be set individually, according to a vector of colors that I have within my code. I am able to do this by assigning a `QBrush` to each `QTableWidgetItem`, when created:

  ```
  QColor col = color_vector.value(i);
  QBrush brush(col);
  item->setData(Qt::BackgroundRole, QVariant(brush));
  ```
- The entire table should have rounded corners (essentially "clipping" the borders of the corner items in the table).

The last part I have not been able to achieve.

---

I have tried the following approaches:

- **Set the stylesheet:**

I can round the corners of the table using this stylesheet:

```
QTableWidget 
{ 
    border: 1px solid;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px 
}
```

Even though this draws a rounded border around the table, the background of the individual cells still "pokes out" at the corners.

I can set the same `border-radius` for `QTableWidget::item`, but then all corners of all cells will be rounded, and not just at the edges of the table. Since `QTableWidgetItem` is itself not a `QWidget`, I don't think I can assign the styling to specific items.

- **Create a `QDelegate`:**

I tried to subclass the `QStyledItemDelegate` and override the `paint()` function. But it doesn't seem to do much. Maybe I'm making an error (still very new to Qt, so very possible), or maybe the changes are overridden by the options I already set in the stylesheet/setData?

This is what I tried for the `paint(painter, option, index)` implementation:

```
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
QPainterPath path;
path.addRoundedRect(option.rect, 5, 5);
painter->fillPath(path, option.backgroundBrush);
QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
```

Then added it to the table widget object:

```
table->setItemDelegateForRow(0, new RoundedCornerDelegate(table));
```

This would not even be the final desired outcome yet (I'd still have to figure out a way to draw only one rounded corner), but it doesn't seem to work: the item's background is still drawn as a pure rectangle. Even if I change the brush in the above code to something different, I don't see a different-color rounded rectangle being drawn on top (maybe below?).

- **Put the table inside a `QFrame`:**

I haven't used `QFrame` before, so I'm not sure if this is the intended use. But I created a `QFrame` in the UI editor, and added the table as a child. Then I tried:

```
ui->frame->setStyleSheet("* { border: 1px solid; border-radius: 5 }");
QWidget* child = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(ui->frame->children().at(0));
ui->frame->setFixedSize(child->size());
```

But this just gives weird results: the border around the `QFrame` only seems to exist where the child does not, and the child is not fully visible.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to achieve this by constructing a QRegion with a rounded rectangular shape and using [`QWidget::setMask(QRegion const&)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setMask-1). However, this is something I haven't tried myself, so feel free to post your own answer if you figure it out.